# Access cmd of Windows server using .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a few scripts and files on a windows server. I want to be able to execute the scripts on a remote server from a local server hosting an ASP.Net web application.

I want to be able to show status and be able to start and stop the script using a button on a webform. I also want to be able to copy files from one place to another on the remote server from my web application on another button via a click event. This can be done by connecting to the Windows Command prompt.

How can I do this securely using the .Net framework?

Comment: Can anybody come up with some other solution? WCF is little complicated thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this one is quite broad. There are a few approaches.

You could invoke a command prompt from within the .net framework using System.Diagnostics and pass it the appropriate arguments. You could invoke script files directly from .Net and these will be handled by the Operating Systems default handler for them. You could invoke powershell with the arguments for loading the script if it is a powershell script.

You could use the native .Net functions for handling file operations if you prefer.

You say you want to do this securely, well creating a server side function that invokes a call to a script is reasonably secure so long as access to those function calls is protected. It depends on your definition of secure.

Please refer to the MSDN for further information on the .Net framework. The documentation should always be your first port of call before asking on stackoverflow. [MSDN - System.Diagnostics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145030%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) browse to the Process class.

A simple example would be as follows.

Create and run a wcf web service on your remote server that'll run the scripts you want to execute. In this service define an ServiceContract that'll define an OperationContract.

**Web Server Control**

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

**Click Handler**

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //consume your web service here.
   ExecuteScript client = new ExecuteScript();
   client.Execute();
}
```

**Remote Server WCF Service**

Create a new WCF Service Application project.

Add a new Service Contract to your service project (Add new Item, WCF Service - call it ExecuteScript)

Create a new class and call it IExecuteScript.

**IExecuteScript.cs** // Define Contract

```
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace Yourservice
{
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IExecuteScript
   {
       [OperationContract]
       void Execute();
   }
}
```

**Expose Endpoints for consumption in your ASP application**

**Web.config**

In your WCF Service project, open web.config and expose your endpoint for the ExecuteScript implementation

```
<services>
<service name="Yourservice.ExecuteScript">
  <endpoint address="" contract="Yourservice.IExecuteScript" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
  <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
</service>
```

**Implement the Service**

**ExecuteScript.svc.cs**

namespace Yournamespace
{

```
public class ExecuteScript: IExecuteScript
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("yourscript");
    }
}
```

}

You'll now need a way to host your WCF service. You can do it in a program of your own making, in IIS, on an ASP.Net server, Windows Service or whatever else takes your fancy. I use Windows Services if the server isn't a dedicated web server.

In your Web Application that has the web form, add a reference to your remote service web service. It'll be something like http://urlOfRemoteServer/ExecuteScript.svc

You can do this in your ASP.Net project by right clicking on References and choosing Add Service Reference. In your click handler call the service. I've highlighted how to do that above.

That's a very rough example but should do what you want.

Visit [WCF For beginners](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/four-steps-to-create-first-wcf-service-for-beginners/) for further information. Also you mentioned security, WCF services can restrict access based on Authorization. Please refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx) MSDN article for further information.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. System Diagnostics talks about interaction system processes, event logs, and performance counters but how shall I connect to windows server?

Comment: See my revised answer for a hint.

Comment: I know this but the script "yourscriptfile" is on windows server and button is on webform in a website. So require to first connect to that server using ip and port. How shall I do it? My question was that

Comment: I've updated my answer with a rough guide on creating a WCF service for achieving what you want.

Comment: Thanks. If I will have doubt will ask you.

Comment: Not a problem. I have linked you to all relevant information and documentation, this will help you far more than I can from this point. If you like my answer and feel it is appropriate would you please accept it.

Comment: Hey this help is great but now I am facing other issue. It is that when I give service reference to WCF in my website and then build, it gives error"Reference.svcmap: Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final method.  Type: 'PDFLibNet.xPDFBinaryReader'.  Assembly: 'PDFLibNet, Version=1.0.6.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=26d87f7d66fb2aee'.   App_WebReferences/IntraScanMgtService/". So it is not letting me object to create. It is due to PDFLib.dll. If I remove it, it works well. Do you have any idea?